# OpenLayers VectorTile with MVT format only show partial marker symbol on tile edge

Tags: mapbox, openlayers

My code like this:

```
var source = new ol.source.VectorTile({

    format:new ol.format.MVT(),

    tileGrid:ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom:22}),

    tilePixelRatio:1,

    url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/xxx.pbf'

    });
```

But on the edge of tiles, marker symbol can not show point intact, it is  cut by edges.
Is there any solution for this? thanks.

Comment: I've seen labels truncated at tile edges, similar to this https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6275  Setting `declutter: true` in the layer options fixed it for me but it seems like a workaround.

Comment: thanks. I think this is intolerable for users using MVT format. Is there any other open source js map library can handle it correctly ?